# Windows Phone Scrolling Chat Viewer

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I have a combined silverlight xna project in which I am rendering a tile based background. Over that, I want to be able to render a scrollable chat window. I tried adding the following:

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Height="480" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="263" 
                  BorderBrush="Black" Background="#8CFFFFFF" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" 
                  Foreground="Black" BorderThickness="2" AllowDrop="False">
        <TextBlock Text="Lots and Lots of text..." TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

When I run the app, the scrolling is laggy. I am not sure why this is, but I assume it has something to with running at the same time as the xna. Any ideas as to why this is happening? Is there a better solution?

Comment: do the performance counters highlight anything?

Comment: Is there an issue if you just use the Silverlight or just the XNA code?

Comment: I figured out the lag issue. My Xna rendering was taking to long an was slowing everything down, not just the Silverlight stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe Cache="BitmapCache" helps you